# Return any_var;

Tags: ajax, javascript

```
function any_funk(){
     $.ajax({   бла бла бла
          success: function(data){

          }
     });
     return data;
}
```

Доброго времени суток. Примерно такая вот конструкция функции. В функции есть аякс запрос, который выполнется асинхронно (синхроно нельзя!). Функция (any_funk) должна вернуть переменную, полученную через аякс. Как можно это осуществить?

Comment: @Ford O Никак. Возвращать [promise равзе что](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112960/)

Comment: @romeo, а почему "разве что"? ))Именно "обещания" и используют для таких целей.

Comment: @Deonis К примеру, в Angular можно значение поместить в $scope и слушать её $watch-ром.

Comment: @romeo, я ж не про библиотечные методы, а об [объекте Promise][1] как таковом. C Angular близко не знакомился, но практически уверен, что там тоже это используется.

   [1]:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise